# Showing size of pie chart in legend of QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, legend, diagram

I'm using a pie chart map in which the size of the pie chart convey an attribute value (scaled size).

Is it possible to show this classification in the legend of QGIS 3?

[image: E.g. of an legend i want to get]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the menu "Diagrams" and navigate to "Legends" entry. Click on "Legend Entries for Diagram Size..."

[image]

Choose "Collapsed Legend"

[image]

The legend will be displayed in layerlist and in printcomposer

[image]