# Showing size of pie chart in legend of ArcMap 10.7.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, maps, chart, arcgis-10.7

[image: PIE CHART MAP]I'm using a pie chart map in which the size of the pie chart convey an attribute value (scaled size).

Is it possible to show this classification in the legend of ArcMap 10.7.1 ?

There is a similar answer for QGIS but I can't 'adapt it to ArcMap 10.7.1 ( [Showing size of pie chart in legend of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314098/showing-size-of-pie-chart-in-legend-of-qgis?rq=1) )

This is an example of a map with pie charts that I need to conclude them to the legend of the map.

Comment: I think this can be done in ArcGIS Pro even if it *may* not be possible in ArcMap.